# If an operator $A$ commutes with the Hamiltonian $H$ do they have common eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, wavefunction, commutator

In this book *Intermediate quantum mechanics* by Hans A. Bethe and Roman Jackiw they write at page 103:

> In the case of spin, the Hamiltonian commutes with the spin operator of each electron $\boldsymbol{s}_i$, since $H$ does not depend on $\mathbf{s}_i$. However we may not conclude from this that $\boldsymbol{s}_i$ can be diagonalized, because the use of antisymmetric wave functions couples the spins to the symmetry of the spatial wave function and thus to the electrostatic energy (see pp. 34 and 63). Indeed $S_{i x} \psi$ does not lie in the Hilbert space of allowed antisymmetric states. Hence it cannot be expanded in terms of antisymmetric wave functions, which would be required if $\mathbf{s}_i$ were diagonal. Total $\operatorname{spin} \mathbf{s}=\Sigma_i \mathbf{s}_i$ is an admissible, symmetric operator, which also commutes with the Hamiltonian.
> $$
> [\mathbf{H}, \mathbf{S}]=\mathbf{0} \tag{6-5}
> $$

where $$
\mathbf{H}=\underbrace{-\frac{\hbar^2}{2 m_e} \sum_{i=1}^n \nabla_i^2-\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{Z e^2}{r_i}}_{\begin{array}{c}
\text { single electron } \\
\text { operator }
\end{array}}+\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n \frac{e^2}{r_{i j}}}_{\begin{array}{c}
\text { two electron } \\
\text { operator }
\end{array}} .
$$

Can someone give  me an example to clarify what they mean, because I had a strong conviction that if an operator $A$ commutes with the Hamiltonian $H$ they would have common eigenstate?

Comment: I think what they are trying to say is that the condition of antisymmetry of the total wave function restricts you to work in a subset of the usual Hilbert space (since you want to work only with physical wave functions, which must be totally antisymmetric for fermions). For example, suppose that there was no spatial part of the wave function and you had two electrons. The usual Hilbert space would be four dimensional, but the space of physical states would be one dimensional, since only the totally antisymmetric wavefunction is allowed by the additional requirement of antisymmetry.

Comment: Let $s:=s_z$ be the spin-$z$ operator of a single-particle. If you deal with $N$ distinguishable particles, then you can lift this operator to the $N$-particle space by $s_1:=s\otimes I_2\otimes \cdots\otimes I_N$, where $I_j$ denotes the identity operator on the $j$-th Hilbert space. For indistinguishable particles, all observables must be invariant under exchange of indices, and hence $s_1$ is not (!) an operator on that space. The same holds for any other $s_i$. But $s=\sum_i s_i$ is (note that all Hilbert spaces are the same then, so $I_j=I_i$)). That is what the quote wants to tell you.

Comment: @ Tobias Fünke I am not understanding why $s=\sum_i s_i$ is an operator on that space and $s_i$ not?

Comment: Well, as I said: It is symmetric under exchange of indices. More precisely, it is invariant under transformation with permutation operators. And you can see that such an operator maps (anti-)symmetric states to (anti-)symmetric states. Your question boils down to the understanding of the first few pages of  a many-body quantum mechanics book, dealing with identical particles.

Comment: Amilton: Regarding the link that @basics provided, he may have read the question that you posted in the TITLE of your post, and not read the entire body of your post. To avoid confusion, you might want to edit the TITLE of your post.

Comment: To add to my above comments: The book is sloppy here, because the notion of "spin of particle 1, which you might represent by the operator $s_1$, is of no meaning, because electrons are indistinguishable, which is reflected by the fact that $s_1$ is not an operator on the $N$-electron Hilbert space. Hence, mathematically, it is wrong to say that $s_1$ and $H$ commute -- the commutator is not even defined, so the statement is useless.

Comment: @Tobias Fünke could you give me a good reference that clarifies your comment?

Comment: Literally any book containing the discussion of identical particles in quantum mechanics. To start, check e.g. Wikipedia (?)

Comment: @TobiasFünke I think it is wrong to say "Literally any book." For example, OP already has one book that contains a discussion of identical particles in quantum mechanics. (The book by Bethe and Jackiw that OP cited, and apparently this literal book doesn't clarify enough.)

Comment: OP you should really be less hostile to those who are taking their time to try to help you out of their own generosity.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what they are trying to say is that the "full" Hilbert space (the direct product space) contains unphysical states and you have to restrict yourself to physical states. We often don't worry about this in introductory quantum mechanics, since we are often concerned with solving single-particle problems. This is probably why Bethe named the book "intermediate" quantum mechanics.

With a two (or more) particle system we have [an **additional** postulate of quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics#Symmetrization_postulate) that must be taken into account: The wave function must be totally antisymmetric (for fermions). (And totally symmetric for bosons.) This limits us to a subset of the "usual" Hilbert space.

This is a little easier to see in the "second-quantized" notation, and it is one reason why the second quantized notation is so important.

As a toy example, suppose that you have *two* electrons and that there is *no spatial dependence* (this makes the hamiltonian of the example trivial, but as I said this is a toy/pedagogical example). Or, more physically, suppose we force both our electrons to be non-interacting and force both to live in a 1s orbital (for some toy reason).

In that case you might expect that there can be *four* two-particle state:
$$
c^\dagger_{\uparrow} c^\dagger_{\downarrow} |0\rangle\tag{1}
$$
$$
c^\dagger_{\uparrow} c^\dagger_{\uparrow} |0\rangle\tag{2?!}
$$
$$
c^\dagger_{\downarrow} c^\dagger_{\downarrow}|0\rangle\tag{3?!}
$$
$$
c^\dagger_{\downarrow} c^\dagger_{\uparrow} |0\rangle\tag{4?}\;,
$$
but actually there is only one state, since the states labelled (2) and (3) are zero (by anticommutation rules) and the state labeled (4) is physically equivalent to the state labelled (1), since it only differs by a total phase (-1).